# VS Code extension for design and source view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any extension in VS Code by using which I can view the source and design of developed HTML at same time similar as we have tabs in visual studio to view html source and design.
Like this-  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/699539

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer

EDIT: Just search VS marketplace for HTML live previewer. I added an example in the link.